# sudo apt update & sudo apt-get update error plz help me

Tags: package-management, updates, update-manager, repository

If I run `sudo apt update && sudo apt-get update` the result looks like this.

[image]

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached *End of Standard Support* last year](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/17/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts-began-on-may-31-2023/), and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (*cost maybe involved*) if you wish but community support (*such as this site*) no longer exists, though SE *Unix & Linux* allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as Canonical provide ESM/Pro services.

Comment: FYI:  Your sources are a mess; with details for a 2023 release though most are for a 2018 EOSS release...  given the large time & number of releases between those; I wonder if you were trying to break your system?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your Ubuntu version isn't supported. It went EOL in april 03.

```
                            Released    End of Standard Support
18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)   Apr 2018    Apr 2023
```

Please update to a supported version .. see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades for information on howto.